# How can I recover original type of an object pointed by base class pointer?

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers

I got 2 classes, B and C, subclassing an abstract class A and a function f with a pointer to A param.
Is there an easy way for f() to detect if the pointer obtained points to a B or a C?

```
class A {
//...
};

class B : public A {
//...
};

class C : public A {
//...
};

int f(A* arg);
```

Comment: Oh, wrong code, it is public, fixing it in the post.

Comment: Yes, you can use RTTI/dynamic-casts.  But best practice is to not do this, and use polymorphism wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself having to do this kind of thing, then you are not using polymorphism and may need to review your design. But you can use `dynamic_cast` and test:

```
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(someAPtr);
if (b)
{
  // cast succeeded, object pointed at is-a-B
}
```

This would be a design using polymorphism:

```
struct A {
  virtual void foo() const {}
};

struct B : A {
  void foo() const override {}
};

struct C : A {
  void foo() const override {}
};

int f(A* arg) { 
  arg->foo();
  return 42; 
}
```

Note that the [`override` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) is C++11. If your compiler doesn't support it, you can omit it. It is just ensuring that I don't mistakenly fail to override a virtual method of a base class.

Comment: ...where the answerer is using `struct` to exploit the fact that all members and inheritance is `public` by default. +1 for showing off ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba No showing off, just extremely lazy and bad at typing :)

Comment: I'll go over the design once again to see if I can avoid this somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You're not supposed to *care*: that's almost the whole point of polymorphism.

However, if you *really* need to know, you have two (reasonable) options:

1) Use a `dynamic_cast`. For a pointer cast, the result will be `nullptr` if the pointer is not the expected type. For a reference cast, an exception will be thrown if the reference is not the expected type.

2) Build a virtual function that the child classes implement that gives, say, an `enum` denoting the type.

(1) is preferred. But do think about why you need this in the first place.

Comment: I really want to avoid knowing,  in general.
The particular context of the question is a case where I'am using an initialize-list contructor that receives anything of the type A* in a container type, and we know a good optimization to do if the A* received is an object of one specific child class.
We are using polymorphism in every other place transparently (currently even in this constructor, but we are wasting lot of run-time computing something we already know the constant answer).